Which precoder is better in this scenario?
I was asked this question on an interview. I think I have provided a good answer, but I think I am missing something. Appreciate any comments.
Problem: In a 2x2 wireless channel, the channel matrix is given as $ \mathbf{H} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} $ and two precoders $\mathbf{P}_1$ and $\mathbf{P}_2$ as $ \mathbf{P}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} $, $ \mathbf{P}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & j \\
1 & -j
\end{bmatrix} $, respectively in an AWGN channel. Which one of the precoders in the following system is better?
My answer: Since after doing $ \mathbf{H}\mathbf{P}_i $ for both scenarios would yield to a diagonal matrix, SNR wise both have similar performance, and the only difference would come as the $ \pi/2$ phase shift with $ \mathbf{P}_2$. I'm not sure if this is enough of an answer and I am missing something here.

$$\mathbf{H} \mathbf{P}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$
$\mathbf{P}_1$  is exactly the same as the channel matrix  $\mathbf{H}$ , so it may lead to maximum signal power alignment with  $\mathbf{H}$  in the real part. This means that if  $\mathbf{P}_1$  is used, the signal will experience constructive alignment with  $\mathbf{H}$.
$$
\mathbf{H} \mathbf{P}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & j \\ 1 & -j \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2j \end{bmatrix}$$
However, $\mathbf{P}_2$ , has complex entries, which can introduce phase diversity due to the imaginary components. This could potentially improve orthogonality between the two streams, which may reduce interference.
Based on the computing the effective channel for each precoder,  $\mathbf{P}_1$  is the better precoder because it provides a high-SNR, orthogonal, and balanced effective channel matrix when combined with  $\mathbf{H}$ in a AWGN channel.

I think you miscalculated the HP2 calculation. It's still gonna be a diagonal matrix

ok.. I did a few small adjustments to make it more accurate.

You transposed P2. It's not correct

ok.. I refined it. Hope this is helpful in resolving this issue.
